# How to avoid copying .exe file into nupkg's lib directory

Tags: c#, nuget

I would automatically pack output (.exe file) of my c# project in some nuget package. Currently I have project-level nuget package (that means I can install this package in project-depended packages.config file). 
Structure of this package:

```
/lib/net40/myexe.exe
/lib/net40/myexe.dll
/myexe.nuspec
```

..and so on.

I will convert this to solution-level package, so I can install it into other solution but I don't need to add my myexe.dll into references. So according nuget documentation "A package is considered a solution-level package if it does not contain any files in its lib, content, or build directories."

I declared files section in my .nuspec file:

```
<files>
  <file src="..\build\$id$.exe" target="bin\" />
</files>
```

But I still have following nupkg structure:

```
/lib/net40/myexe.exe
/lib/net40/myexe.dll
/bin/myexe.exe
/bin/myexe.dll
/myexe.nuspec
```

How to avoid /lib/ directory in my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set Tool flag:

```
nuget pack <PackageProject.csproj> -outputDirectory <OutputDirectory> -BasePath <OutputDirectory> -Tool
```